# Cannot execute multiple file in c programming xCODE

Tags: c, xcode

[As you can see above I have 1 file in my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlDtc.png) 
[second file is added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYjUV.png)
[When i try to execute one of my file i encounter with this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCMSm.png)

Can you please help me with this error.
Thank you.

I mentioned problem above

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You'll need to click and get details on that error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `main` functions in your project, one in each file. A C program can have only one `main` function.

Remove one of the `main` functions or rename one of them to get the project to build.

If you're writing lots of short C programs, you shouldn't use Xcode. With Xcode you have to create a new project for each program. Use a text editor like Visual Studio Code, TextMate, or Sublime Text instead. Text editors like these have bundles you can install that let you build and run C programs from within the editor.